# iOS14 introducing errors with @State bindings

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios14

The below swiftUI code was working fine with iOS13, but on testing with iOS14, I'm getting fatal errors caused by the force-unwrapped optional when trying to display the modal sheet. As far as I can tell, the sheet should never try to present with a nil value for selectedModel, as showingDetails is only ever made true after assigning selectedModel?

```
struct SpeakerBrandMenu: View {
    var filteredSpeakers: [Speaker] {
        // An array of Speaker objects
        }
        
    @State var selectedModel: Speaker?
    @State private var showingDetails = false

    var body: some View {
        List{       
        ForEach(filteredSpeakers) { speaker in
            HStack {
                Button(action: {
                    self.selectedModel = speaker
                    self.showingDetails = true
                }) {
                    SpeakerModelRow(speaker: speaker).contentShape(Rectangle())
                }
                .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())

                Spacer()
                
                Button(
                //unrelated
                ).padding(5)
              }
            }
        } .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingDetails) { SpeakerDetailView(speaker: self.selectedModel!, showSheet: self.$showingDetails).environmentObject(self.favoriteSpeakers).environmentObject(self.settings)}
               
          .navigationBarTitle(Text(brand), displayMode: .inline)
    }
}
```

Interestingly, if I unwrap it as `speaker: self.selectedModel ?? filteredSpeakers[0]`it behaves exactly as expected: The first time pressing any of the menu items, the first item is passed to the sheet, but on dismissing the sheet and selecting another item it then shows the correct item every time. So it's as though the button to assign selectedModel is trying to display the sheet before it has had time assign it.

Comment: View creation order is undefined, so you should not rely on it, ever. The most appropriate solution for your scenario is via `.sheet(item...` modifier as in @pawello2222 answer below.

Comment: I've just burnt time with this issue on switching to iOS 14 - pretty bad bug on Apple's part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like in iOS 14 the `sheet(isPresented:content:)` is now created beforehand, so any changes made to `selectedModel` are ignored.

Try using `sheet(item:content:)` instead:

```
var body: some View {
    List {
        ...
    }
    .sheet(item: self.$selectedModel) {
        SpeakerDetailView(speaker: $0)
    }
}
```

and dismiss the sheet using `@Environment(\.presentationMode)`:

```
struct SpeakerDetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    var speaker: Speaker

    var body: some View {
        Text("Speaker view")
            .onTapGesture {
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for this situation. But I can't see how to implement this in a similar situation where I want to choose from several sheets depending on the button pressed. I've edited my post with an example of what I mean

Comment: @Neil Please don't edit your post - one question per post. Create another post with your new question - I'll try to help you there.

Comment: Sorry, follow-up question here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63938343/displaying-a-sheet-from-multiple-options-in-swiftui Thanks!

Comment: @pawello2222 How did you find out that `sheet(isPresented:content:)` is now created beforehand? I tried setting up a breakpoint in my `init` method of my sheet and it wasn't called prematurely when using `sheet(isPresented:content:)`.