# SwiftUI - changing property in "onAppear" doesn't change sheet when presented

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a button, and when it's pressed, I present a sheet. This sheet displays `options.categories` in a `List`.

The problem is that when I set `options.categories` inside `ContentView`'s `onAppear`, the sheet doesn't reflect the changes. It's still an empty list.

```
struct ViewOptions {
    public var categories = [String]()
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var presentingModal = false
    @State var options = ViewOptions()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tap to present:")
            Button("Present") { presentingModal = true } /// set presentingModal to true, to present the sheet
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentingModal) {
                ModalView(options: options)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            options.categories = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
        }
    }
}

struct ModalView: View {
    var options: ViewOptions
    var body: some View {
        List { /// display options.categories in a List
            ForEach(options.categories, id: \.self) { word in
                Text(word)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result (nothing is shown!):

[image]

But if I comment out the `.sheet` and just embed `ModalView` inside `ContentView`, it works.

```
VStack {
    Text("Tap to present:")
       Button("Present") { presentingModal = true }
//     .sheet(isPresented: $presentingModal) { /// get rid of the sheet
           ModalView(options: options)
//     }
}
.onAppear {
    options.categories = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
}
```

[image]

How can I keep on using a sheet, but have the list update when I change the values?

Comment: This might be related to iOS 14 changes: [iOS14 introducing errors with @State bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63928736/8697793)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use on appear. You can simply initialize a new ViewOptions object:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var presentingModal = false
    @State var options: ViewOptions = .init(categories:  ["one", "two", "three", "four"])

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Tap to present:")
            Button("Present") {
                presentingModal = true
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $presentingModal) {
                ModalView(options: options)
            }
        }
    }
}
```