# Presenting a Sheet modally, @State value is not changing

Tags: swiftui

I have tried much time on it but I couldn't figure out why it is not working.

The problem is when I tap the button, the new value inside the sheet is not updated. It always show the same value which is set up in start.

```
 @State var value:String = "empty"
 @State var explorePageIsEnabled:Bool = false
    
   VStack{
    
    Button("tap me"){
        value = "the new one"
        exploreStatusIsEnabled.toggle()
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $exploreStatusIsEnabled, content: {
        Text(value)
    })
    
}
```

Deployment target is IOS 14+

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS14 introducing errors with @State bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928736/ios14-introducing-errors-with-state-bindings)

Answer (score 2):

Create a separate struct view for text and use `Binding`.

```
struct SheetView: View {
    @Binding var value: String
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(value)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var value: String = "empty"
    @State private var explorePageIsEnabled: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Button("tap me"){
                value = "the new one"
                explorePageIsEnabled.toggle()
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $explorePageIsEnabled, content: {
                SheetView(value: $value)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! But why @State does not work on this condition? Could you please explain?

Comment: It because when you changed the value of any state var then the view is recreated, the value of the state doesn't change so it gives you the original value instead of the updated value.

Comment: @RajaKishan I added a Text(value) on top of the button in the code which is in the question , then it worked as expected ?

Comment: @Asperi can you give some explanation to above comment ?

Comment: @Yodagama It's rather the issue with sheet creation in iOS 14. It looks like the `sheet(isPresented:content:)` is now created beforehand, so any changes made to `value` are ignored. The *correct* solution IMHO is to use `sheet(item:content:)` as in https://stackoverflow.com/q/63928736/8697793 - this way the sheet will be created basing on the `item` parameter.