# SwiftUI List state not being persisted with contextmenu

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a simple view that uses `ForEach` to list an array. Each item in the list has a context menu which captures the object and sets up a sheet for that object. However, the initial execution of it does not set the state, whereas subsequent executions do.

Here is a short program illustrating the problem:

```
struct MyTestView : View {
    var people = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    @State var collectedPerson = "Initial"
    @State var showingActionSheet = false
    var body : some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.people, id: \.self) { person in
                Text(person)
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button("Edit \(person)") { // person is correct here
                            self.collectedPerson = person
                            self.showingActionSheet = true
                        }
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingActionSheet) {
                        Text(self.collectedPerson) // State is not set the first time
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initially, the screen loads with "Initial", which is incorrect:

[image]

If I pull up the context menu again, this time, the state is set properly (suppose I pull up the context menu on B):

[image]

Does anyone know why the initial state seems to not be set?

Comment: Looks like the `.sheet(isPresented:)` is created differently in iOS 14. Does this answer your question? [iOS14 introducing errors with @State bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63928736/ios14-introducing-errors-with-state-bindings)

Comment: That was it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is possible solution for your code snapshot - use `sheet(item:_)` modifier

```
struct MyTestView : View {
    var people = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    @State var collectedPerson: String?

    var body : some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.people, id: \.self) { person in
                Text(person)
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button("Edit \(person)") {
                            self.collectedPerson = person
                        }
                    }
                    // item required to be identifiable
                    .sheet(item: self.$collectedPerson) { person in
                        Text(person)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension String: Identifiable {
    public var id: String { self }
}
```

**Alternate**: to use separated view for edit in sheet and inject there state property via binding

```
struct MyTestView : View {
    var people = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
    @State var collectedPerson = "Initial"
    @State var showingActionSheet = false
    var body : some View {
        List {
            ForEach(self.people, id: \.self) { person in
                Text(person)
                    .contextMenu {
                        Button("Edit \(person)") { // person is correct here
                            self.collectedPerson = person
                            self.showingActionSheet = true
                        }
                    }
                    .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingActionSheet) {
                        MyTestEditView(person: self.$collectedPerson)
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MyTestEditView: View {
    @Binding var person: String
    var body: some View {
        Text(person)
    }
}
```

Both tested and worked with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1