# Cant get my sheet to display the right information

Tags: swift, swiftui

```
/*
```

I have an .onTapGesture on my MapAnnottions. If I press the MapAnnotations for the first time a
black/empty DisplayBusinessSheet will appear. I want it to display a certain type of
information. If I dismiss the sheet and press the same annotation I only get a black/empty
sheet. If I dismiss the sheet again and press another location/ MapAnnotation in my map it
displays the right information. I reallyyyyyy don't know what's happening, been stuck for solongggg, please help me <3

*/

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift


struct MapView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var firebaseModel: FirebaseModel
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    
    @State var region: MKCoordinateRegion
    @State var businessSheetPresented = false
    @State var pressedLocation: Location? = nil
    @State var pressedUser: User? = nil
    
    var locationModel = LocationModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack{
            if let firebaseListOfLocations = firebaseModel.listOfLocations {
                Map(coordinateRegion: $region,
                    showsUserLocation: true,
                    annotationItems: firebaseListOfLocations) { location in
                    
                    //Every place has a marker
                    //anchorPoint is where we attatch the coordinates to the annotation
                    MapAnnotation(coordinate: location.userLocation!.coordinate, anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)) {
                        Image(systemName: "mappin")
                            .resizable()
                            .foregroundColor(ColorManager.darkPink)
                            .frame(width: 11, height: 30)
                            .onTapGesture(count: 1, perform: {
                                self.pressedLocation = location.userLocation!
                                self.pressedUser = location
                                
                                print("Location name: \(location.userLocation!.id)")
                                print("Pressed Location name: \(pressedLocation)")
                                print("Pressed USer Name \(pressedUser!.name)")
                                print("Pressed USer Name \(pressedUser!)")
                                
                                
                                businessSheetPresented = true
                            })
                        
                    }
                }.ignoresSafeArea()
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $businessSheetPresented) {
            if let pressedUser = pressedUser {
                DisplayBusinessSheet(user: pressedUser)
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            locationModel.askForPermission()
            addUserCollectionListener()
            print("LOCATIONS: \(firebaseModel.listOfLocations!.count)")
            
        }
        
    }
    
    private func addUserCollectionListener(){
        
        if let currentUserData = userData.userDocRef {
            
            currentUserData.addSnapshotListener{ documentSnapshot, error in
                guard let document = documentSnapshot else {
                    print("Error fetching document: \(error!)")
                    return
                }
                guard let data = document.data() else {
                    print("Document data was empty.")
                    return
                }
                try! self.userData.currUserData = document.data(as: UserDataModel.self)
            }
        }
    }
  
}


//Here is the sheet I'm trying to present 
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct DisplayBusinessSheet: View {
    
    @State var user: User
    
    private let certefiedTitle = "Certifierad"
    private let myProductsTitle = "Mina Produkter"
    private let aboutMeTitle = "Lite om mig"
    private let socialMediaTitle = "Instagram"
    
    let notYetPostedInfo = "Information is under cunstroction"
    let heightFourth = UIScreen.main.bounds.height/4
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                ScrollView {
                    
                    Image("nailimage")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(height: heightFourth)
                        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .top)

                    
                    if let businessUser = user.businessUser {
                        Text("\(user.name)")
                            .foregroundColor(ColorManager.darkPink)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .font(.system(size: 20))
                            .padding()

                        TitleText(
                            title: certefiedTitle, textImage: Image(systemName: "link"),
                            textContent: businessUser.certifiedIn)
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)
                        
                        TitleText(
                            title: myProductsTitle, textImage: Image(systemName: "wand.and.stars"),
                            textContent: businessUser.productType)
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)
                        
                        TitleText(
                            title: aboutMeTitle, textImage: Image(systemName: "heart.text.square"),
                            textContent: businessUser.aboutMe)
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)
                        
                        TitleText(
                            title: socialMediaTitle, textImage: Image(systemName: "link"),
                            textContent: businessUser.socialMedia)
                            .padding(.bottom, 4)
                    }
                    
                }.frame(height: heightFourth * 3)
            }.onAppear{
                print("Display Business User Name: \(user.name)")
                print("Display Business User Certefied: \(user.businessUser!.certifiedIn)")
                print("Display Business User Product type: \(user.businessUser!.productType)")
                print("Display Business User About me: \(user.businessUser!.aboutMe)")
                print("Display Business User Social media: \(user.businessUser!.socialMedia)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iOS14 introducing errors with @State bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63928831/8697793)

Comment: No it didn't :/ I have tried to use a full screen instead of a sheet and I have the same problem, don't know if its the sheet or if its a problem with my onTapGesture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iOS 14 `sheet(isPresented:content:)` is now created beforehand and the view is not refreshed when the `$businessSheetPresented` changes.

Instead of `.sheet(isPresented:content:)`

```
.sheet(isPresented: $businessSheetPresented) {
    if let pressedUser = pressedUser {
        DisplayBusinessSheet(user: pressedUser)
    }
}
```

you should use `.sheet(item:content:)`

```
.sheet(item: $pressedUser) { user in
    DisplayBusinessSheet(user: pressedUser)
}
```

*Note: with the above solution you don't really need `businessSheetPresented` unless it's used in some other place apart from triggering the sheet.*